# Dynamic replacement in sed command based on a value in the string

Tags: unix, sed

I have a HTML file with following code
`<input name="Patient_Id" type="text" id="Patient_Id" tabindex="10" class="forms" oncopy="return false" oncut="return false" onpaste="return false" autocomplete="off" style="font-family:Arial;">`

Now I have to add a **value** in the end depending on what the **tabindex** value is

For example

I am expecting a output as
`<input name="Patient_Id" type="text" id="Patient_Id" tabindex="10" class="forms" oncopy="return false" oncut="return false" onpaste="return false" autocomplete="off" style="font-family:Arial;" value=tabindex10>`

Similarly if the input is
`<input name="Patient_Name" type="text" id="Patient_Name" tabindex="11" class="forms" oncopy="return false" oncut="return false" onpaste="return false" autocomplete="off" style="font-family:Arial;">`

I am looking for output as
`<input name="Patient_Name" type="text" id="Patient_Name" tabindex="11" class="forms" oncopy="return false" oncut="return false" onpaste="return false" autocomplete="off" style="font-family:Arial;" value=tabindex11>`

Here my goal is to replace the input tag on place in the file using sed command and then render the html page

Comment: [Do not parse html with regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags).

Answer (score 0):

With the following input:

```
<input name="Patient_Id" type="text" id="Patient_Id" tabindex="10" class="forms" oncopy="return false" oncut="return false" onpaste="return false" autocomplete="off" style="font-family:Arial;">abc</input>
```

The following comand:

```
xmlstarlet ed -a '/input' --type attr -n value -v "tabindex$(xmlstarlet sel -t -v '/input/@tabindex' inputfile)" inputfile
```

outputs:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<input name="Patient_Id" type="text" id="Patient_Id" tabindex="10" class="forms" oncopy="return false" oncut="return false" onpaste="return false" autocomplete="off" style="font-family:Arial;" value="tabindex10">abc</input>
```

Comment: xmlstarlet is not installed on the machine and will need approvals to get it done. The TAT of this would be larger.

Comment: Can it be quickly done through sed command